# Setup a valid connection string for SimpleMembership

Tags: c#, entity-framework, connection-string, sqlclient

I am trying to setup a valid connection string for my database so that my `WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection` method can point to my database.

Here's my connection string:

```
<add name="Database_Entities1" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.DAL.Entities.MTG_Model.csdl|res://*/Models.DAL.Entities.MTG_Model.ssdl|res://*/Models.DAL.Entities.MTG_Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=**.**.***.***;initial catalog=Model_Name;persist security info=True;user id=*****;password=*********;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework;Pooling=True;Max Pool Size=1000&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

The problem here is the provider name which is `System.Data.EntityClient`. I actually need it to point toward `System.Data.SqlClient`, but when I try to copy/paste the connection string and replace the `System.Data.EntityClient` with the other provider name, I get such crash like `Keyword not supported: 'metadata'.`.

So my understanding is that calling my method like this:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private static SimpleMembershipInitializer _initializer;
    private static object _initializerLock = new object();
    private static bool _isInitialized;

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext _filterContext)
    {
        // Ensure ASP.NET Simple Membership is initialized only once per app start
        LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized(ref _initializer, ref _isInitialized, ref _initializerLock);
    }

    private class SimpleMembershipInitializer
    {
        public SimpleMembershipInitializer()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<Database_Entities1>(null);

            try
            {
                using (var context = new Database_Entities1())
                {
                    if (!context.Database.Exists())
                    {
                        // Create the SimpleMembership database without Entity Framework migration schema
                        ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.CreateDatabase();
                    }
                }

                WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("Database_Entities2", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", true);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("The ASP.NET Simple Membership database could not be initialized. For more information, please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=256588", ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Where `Database_Entities2` is:

```
<add name="Database_Entities2" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.DAL.Entities.MTG_Model.csdl|res://*/Models.DAL.Entities.MTG_Model.ssdl|res://*/Models.DAL.Entities.MTG_Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=**.**.***.***;initial catalog=Model_Name;persist security info=True;user id=*****;password=*********;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework;Pooling=True;Max Pool Size=1000&quot;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Does not work because an SqlClient connection string does not work that way. Can anyone help me achive what I'm trying to do? Thanks a lot!

**EDIT**

Two additionnal piece of information: I have this connection string:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MyApp-20130829080410;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MyApp-20130829080410.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Which was working; however, as you can see, it does not point toward my database, so if I try to retrieve any users in the table "UserProfile", it is not possible since the table was created in the local database (which I don't know why I have), and not in the main one (Database_Entities1), hence this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `SimpleMembershipProvider` expects a **normal** connection string, not an entity framework connection string. You need to define a separate connection string that points to the same database as your entity framework connection string and use that:

```
<add name="MembershipDB" 
    connectionString="Data Source=**.**.***.***;Initial Catalog=Model_Name;[...]" 
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: YEAH! It worked! I will post my result up there, but at last it seems to work properly, thanks a lot!

Comment: @HerveS It is one of my annoyances with entity framework (Database first). I'd really like to know who at Microsoft thought it was a good idea to embed a connection string inside a connection string (which is essentially what the entity framework connection string is).

Comment: The problem that I have right now is that I have 2 connections, one for my diagram and one for the simple membership attributes. How can I acccess the UserProfile in the `Database_Entity1` model?

Comment: @HerveS That is probably better as a separate question, but in general: just add the table to your model.

Comment: Found out that the table was indeed added to the model, I just needed to update my model diagram. :)

Answer (score -1):

If you use `Entity Framework` the connection string would be created by the IDE. And from your description i guess you created that connection string by your own, not via IDE.

So the IDE would place something like this in your app.config:

```
<add name="libraryEntities1" connectionString="metadata=res://*/privlibDBmodel.csdl|res://*/privlibDBmodel.ssdl|res://*/privlibDBmodel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=[yourserver];initial catalog=library;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

To create the connection in your program you could use this:

```
libraryEntities1 dbconn = new libraryEnitits1();
```

Now you could handle the connections via dbcon object.

Comment: Well, you are right and this works if I try to load any data from my database normally. However the connection string needed for `SimpleMembership` is not the same needed as the one I use for normal database work.