# MVC 4 SimpleMembership Model first

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

I have researched for the last couple days on Stack and other coding sites and cant seem to find a fix for my problem.

My goal is to configure simplemembership with my own database.(yes i have done a search and none of them answer my question)

I'm using visual studio 2013 and entity framework 4

I used the internet application template for asp.net mvc 4, that has already built in login.

I do as everyone else on line has done and seems to work for some, but most of the time they are left with no answer at all.

when i run my code and set the break points in the SimpleMembershipInitializer class. When I run it and click on register or login I step through the code and when it gets down to

`WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("AdventureWorksEntities", "mvcUser", "userID", "userName", autoCreateTables: false);`

I get this error: *"No user table found that has the name \"mvcUser\"."*

what I know:

- I know there is a table named "mvcUser"
- I can CRUD the table and attribute in the table with in the site

If you want screen shots or more code please let me know.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575311/using-simplemembership-with-ef-model-first?rq=1) is something similar to what I am looking/talking about but I don't understand what is meant by number 2 and 3 in the selected answer.

**Controller**

```
  [Authorize]
  [InitializeSimpleMembership]
  public class AccountController : Controller
  {

    private AdventureWorksEntities db = new AdventureWorksEntities();
```

This is at the top ^^

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Attempt to register the user
            try
            {
                WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.userName, model.UserPassword);
                WebSecurity.Login(model.userName, model.UserPassword);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            catch (MembershipCreateUserException e)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(e.StatusCode));
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

**Model**

```
public class UsersContext : DbContext
{
    public UsersContext()
        : base("AdventureWorksEntities")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
}
```

**Web.config**

```
 <connectionStrings>    
 <add name="AdventureWorksEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.AdventureworksContext.csdl|res://*/Models.AdventureworksContext.ssdl|res://*/Models.AdventureworksContext.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=LEMN-476W-IT;initial catalog=AdventureWorks;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
 </connectionStrings>
```

**Filter\InitializerSimpleMembership.cs**

```
private class SimpleMembershipInitializer
    {
        public SimpleMembershipInitializer()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<UsersContext>(null);

            try
            {
                using (var context = new UsersContext())
                {
                    if (!context.Database.Exists())
                    {
                        // Create the SimpleMembership database without Entity Framework migration schema
                        ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.CreateDatabase();
                    }
                }

                WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("AdventureWorksEntities", "mvcUser", "userID", "userName", autoCreateTables: false);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("The ASP.NET Simple Membership database could not be initialized. For more information, please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=256588", ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"No user table found that has the name XXXXX"* means that you can't use Entity Framework connection string (`EntityClient` provider) to initialize database connection for `SimpleMembershipProvider`, it must be initialized with a plain `SqlClient` provider connection string.

There are 2 solutions to solve this problem:

**Single Connection String (EDM Only)**

Use `EntityConnectionStringBuilder` instance to generate `SqlClient` provider connection string, then point `InitializeDatabaseConnection` to use generated connection string:

```
private class SimpleMembershipInitializer 
{
    public SimpleMembershipInitializer() 
    {
        // initializer settings here

        var connectionBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder("AdventureWorksEntities");
        string sqlConnectionString = connectionBuilder.ConnectionString;

        WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection(sqlConnectionString, "mvcUser", "userID", "userName", autoCreateTables: false);
    }
}
```

**Dual Connection String**

Add a new element on `connectionStrings` part in web.config file which includes `SqlClient` provider, so that it will looks like this (one for SQL Server & another one for EF):

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="AdventureWorksDatabase" connectionString="Data Source=LEMN-476W-IT;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
   <add name="AdventureWorksEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.AdventureworksContext.csdl|res://*/Models.AdventureworksContext.ssdl|res://*/Models.AdventureworksContext.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=LEMN-476W-IT;initial catalog=AdventureWorks;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Then, set `InitializeDatabaseConnection` to use newly created connection string:

```
private class SimpleMembershipInitializer 
{
    public SimpleMembershipInitializer() 
    {
        // initializer settings here

        WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("AdventureWorksDatabase", "mvcUser", "userID", "userName", autoCreateTables: false);
    }
}
```

NB: The accepted answer from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575311/using-simplemembership-with-ef-model-first?rq=1) mentions how to convert Code First to Model First with `SimpleMembershipProvider`, but here you have Model First setup from start.

Related issues:

[Can SimpleMembership and Entity Framework share a connection string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17000869/can-simplemembership-and-entity-framework-share-a-connection-string)

[Setup a valid connection string for SimpleMembership](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21458638/setup-a-valid-connection-string-for-simplemembership)

Comment: The Dual connection is what working for me. Thank you for the explaining it.